# Next.js on Firebase Functions with Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I'm trying to deploy a `Next.js` app to `Firebase Functions`.

```
import next from 'next'
import {https} from 'firebase-functions'

const server = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  conf: {distDir: '.next'}
})

const nextjsHandler = server.getRequestHandler()

exports.app = https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  await server.prepare()
  return await nextjsHandler(req, res)
})
```

The problem is that Typescript complains in the following two places:

1. For the line `conf: {distDir: '.next'}` it shows the following error (which is strange as I find in [Next.js source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/e65c56e7e6c16c3c971984ce7acd161bca6b9c2f/packages/next/server/config-shared.ts#L44) that `NextConfig` should accept `distDir`):

   `Type '{ distDir: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NextConfig'.`
2. For the line `return await nextjsHandler(req, res)`, specifically the `res`:

   `Type error: Argument of type 'Response<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ServerResponse'. Property 'req' is optional in type 'Response<any>' but required in type 'ServerResponse'.`

I would really appreaciate any help on resolving the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- After looking at your code I believe you are following either [this
  blog](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/deploying-next-js-application-on-firebase-platform-using-cloud-function-with-firebase-hosting-920157f03267) or [this github link](https://github.com/milon27/next-js-portfolio) to deploy your Next JS application
  to Firebase Function.
- I followed both of them and at first got an error in the function
  code as the code uses `const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';` but after following the blog I observed that there was
  no environment variable in the application, which was causing the
  error in the code.
- So I added an empty `.env` file and a `.env.sample` file as [mentioned
  here](https://github.com/milon27/next-js-portfolio/blob/master/.env.sample) in the application and after that I could deploy the
  function without any error.
- So except the above I don’t see any error in the code you have
  provided.